# Can "give birth" be used figuratively?

Tags: phrase-request

Reading a question, I was reminded of an Italian expression: *La montagna ha partorito un topolino* (literally, "the mountain gave birth to a little mouse").

Similar expressions are *ha partorito un libro* ("he gave birth to a book"), and *vediamo che idea hai partorito* ("let's see which idea you gave birth to"). All those expressions are used figuratively, and in jokes; they generally refer to how long it took to do something, or to the fact the result is less than expected.

Can I use *give birth* figuratively, or is there a better expression that I can use?

Comment: Sure. All such expressions can be used metaphorically. Whether you'd want to use the language of parturition, however, depends wholly on context. I don't think this metaphor has the same semantic value in English, though, unless the setup prepares the reader/listener for it. Despite the fact that almost any fertile female impregnated by almost any fertile male, regardless of other natural or acquired attributes, can deliver a baby, it's something too sacred to joke about in the USA: FETTFCS (Fanatics for the Ethical Treatment of Teleologically Human Fetal Cells) will jump on your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figurative use of *give birth to* is perfectly fine.

In fact, I would not surprised to find that the figurative use is more common than the literal. In ordinary speech we say so-and-so *had* a baby, a son, a daughter, twins, and so forth; *give birth* mostly occurs in formal contexts.

Just for fun, I ran a Google Books search on *gave birth to*; here are the first-page results:

> The Girl Who Gave Birth to Rabbits: A True Medical Mystery
>   The Woman Who Gave Birth to Rabbits
>   Weapons Grade: How Modern Warfare Gave Birth to Our High-Tech World
>   Primeval kinship: how pair-bonding gave birth to human society
>   Cro-Magnon: How the Ice Age Gave Birth to the First Modern Humans
>   The Woman Who Gave Birth to Her Mother: Tales of Transformation in [Women's Lives]
>   Hot Potato: How Washington and New York Gave Birth to Black [Basketball]
>   City of Scoundrels: The 12 Days of Disaster That Gave Birth to [Modern Chicago]
>   A rational and historical account of the principles which gave [birth to the late rebellion...]
>   Maternally Speaking: I Gave Birth to Four Eggs! (One Scrambled, [Fried, Over Easy & Sunny Side Up)]

Comment: ...I seriously did not need to know the story of The Girl Who Gave Birth to Rabbits. Damn you Wikipedia. +1 despite the fact that I think this is going to give me nightmares... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Sense 44 of *give* in the OED is "give birth to", which is divided into two sub-senses, literal and figurative:

> **44. give birth to. a.** To bear; bring forth. **b.** *fig.* To produce; result in.

It contains examples of both senses.  Here are the figurative examples:

> - 1712 Addison *Spect.* No. 267 ⁋6 Æneas's Settlement in Italy produced the Cæsars, and gave Birth to the Roman Empire.
> - 1862 Stanley *Jew. Ch.* (1877) I. xii. 231 A fit receptacle of a nation which was to give birth to the Sacred Book of all lands.

That doesn't mean it *always* makes sense to use the term figuratively.  It's rather literary, so if I said something like "he gave birth to a book" conversationally, I'd expect a response like "wow, that sounds painful."  But I think the metaphor is still appropriate in writing, and I'd expect to see it from time to time, especially if the object is something non-physical (thus ruling out the literal interpretation).